# Add/remove items dynamically with jQuery and HTML

Tags: jquery, field

This is my HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <input type="button" id="add" value="New Thing">
    <div id="addNew_1" class="new">
        <select name="select_1">
            <div id="options">
                <option value="nothing">Nothing</option>
                <option value="snothing">Second Nothing</option>
            </div>
        </select>
        <input type="text" id="input_1" value="Here goes your stuff">
        <input type="button" id="newField_1" value="New Field For Stuff">
        <br>
        <br>
    </div>
</div>
```

And this is my jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var select = 1;
    var divid = 1;
    var options = $('#options');
    $('#newField_' + divid).on('click', function () {
        select++;
        var content = '<select name=select_' + select + '>' + options + '</select><input type="text" name="input_' + select + '" value="Here goes your stuff"><input type="button" class="remove"  id="remove_' + select + '"  value="Remove this field!"><br><br>';
        $('#addNew_' + divid).append(content);
        $('.remove').on('click', remThis);
    });

    function remthis() {
        $(this).parents('div').remove();
    }
    $('#add').on('click', function () {
        divid++;
        select++;
        var thing = '<div id="addNew' + divid + '" class="new"><select name=select_' + select + '>' + options + '</select><input type="text" name="input_' + select + '" value="Here goes your stuff"><input type="button" id="newField_' + divid + '" value="New Field For Stuff"></div><br><br>';
        $('#container').append(thing);
    });

});
```

This script's purpose is to add one select and one input fields in the parent div by clicking "Add New Field For Stuff" and add a new div with the same content by clicking the "New Thing" button. 
Where I'm stuck:

- I want to dynamically add/remove every field in every generated div. I've managed to add fields, but it adds only when it displays the div
  from html. If I generate another one, I can't do that anymore. I
  don't get it!
- I want to dynamically add/remove divs. Again, I've
  managed to add new divs, but I have no idea about how to dynamically
  delete a div.
- I want to add a title on every div (for example Div #1,
  Div#2...etc) so when I delete the second div for example, the user
  can still see Div #1, Div#2, Div#3, etc...
- Another issue is that I
  can't add options on every generated . I needed to add the
  options this way because I will take values for every div with php,
  if I give the same name to every , I can't post this in a
  form. So I need to have a different name on every input type and
  select I generate.

I'm a newbie, 3 days ago I had no idea about jQuery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to use delegated on event for dynamically added elements

try this

```
 $('#container').on('click','#newField_' + divid, function () {
   .....
```

it would be real easy if you use class instead of `id`...

```
<div class="addNew" class="new">
..
<input type="text" class="input" value="Here goes your stuff">
<input type="button" class="newField" value="New Field For Stuff">
```

and use class selector..

```
$('#container').on('click','.newField', function () {
   .....
```

no need to take care of `divid` and `select` and its counter

**note: you missed name attribute of your input element**

**updated**

using `clone()` since i think you are creating the same element and appending it... and you can post you name as array to PHP so that you can use loop to get all the inputs value

```
$('#container').on('click','.newField', function () {
      var newthing=$('div.addNew:first').clone()
                                        .find('.newField')
                                        .removeClass('newField')
                                        .addClass('remove')
                                        .val('Remove Field!')
                                        .end();

     $('#container').append(newthing);
});

 $('#container').on('click','.remove', function () {

    $(this).parent().remove();
});


$('#add').on('click', function () {

    var thing=$('div.addNew:first').clone();
    $('#container').append(thing);
});
```

fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/bipen/ADgAE/3/)

Comment: As I said, I'm a beginner. I shall use $('#container').on('click','#newField_' + divid, function () { instead of what?

Comment: if you are using class..then there is no need to increment id...neither the class.

Comment: I understand that, but let me explain my project: 
Every time I press a button, I need generate a new div wich contains: an input field, a selector and an "Add New Field" button. When I press the "Add New Field" button, it will add a new selector, an input field and a "Remove this field" button. This button removes that field, the input field and removes itself. So I need to increment something, because the button with de id 3 removes selector and field with the same id for example. Here is my program, but it's not working 100% http://jsfiddle.net/ADgAE/2/

Comment: And I need to increment name too, because I will take all the values with PHP with a `for` function (I guess... or maybe I will fild an alternative). I will need to take the name and the content for each div.

Comment: ok.. modified you jsfiddle.. check this fiddle out.. http://jsfiddle.net/bipen/ADgAE/3/

Comment: Does it add another name on every field and `select`?

Comment: I've found an issue: if I generate 3 divs and I press "add new field" on the second one, it adds a new field on the third one...

Comment: no it doesnot.. it adds the name as array... `"name=select_1[]"` and `name="input_1[]"` ..so when you post this form... the value is posted in an array... like input_1=['tet','test','testt'] (if you add three fields)..and you can get this by `$_POST['input_1']`..

Comment: ok so if you need as such then .. yes!! you need unique parent container (ids).... and can modify my codes thougn, i don't think it will take long.. :)

Comment: @sergiu .. ok !! here you go!! without using ids http://jsfiddle.net/bipen/ADgAE/4/ ..replace `$('#container').append(newthing);` with `$(this).parent().after(newthing);` in first click function